# logstash - output single event into multiple line output file

Tags: logstash

I have a  jdbc input with a select statement. each row in the restult set has 3 columns. `c1`, `c2`, `c3`. the event emitted has the following structure:

```
{"c1":"v1", "c2":"v2", "c3":"v3", "file_name":"tmp.csv"}
```

I want to output the values in a file in the following manner:

```
output file:
v1
v2
v3
```

this is the output configuration:

```
file {
                path => "/tmp/%{file_name}"
                codec => plain { format => "%{c1}\n%{c2}\n%{c3}"  }
                write_behavior => "overwrite"
                flush_interval => 0
        }
```

but what is generated is

```
outputfile:
v1\nv2\nv3
```

is the plain codec plugin not the one i need? is there any other codec plugin for the output file plugin that i can use? or is the only option i have is to write my own plugin?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but maybe this helps others. Although it looks funky, you should be able to get away with simply hitting Enter within the format string (using the `line` codec).

```
file {
    path => "/tmp/%{file_name}"
    codec => line {
        format => "%{c1}
%{c2}
%{c3}"
    }
    write_behavior => "overwrite"
    flush_interval => 0
}
```

Not the prettiest approach, but it works. Not sure if there is a better way.

Answer (score -1):

what you are looking for is the line codec plugin: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-line.html

Comment: Could you indicate what configuration you used? I tried to do it with the line codec and couldn't.

Comment: what output do you get?

Comment: I'm getting the same thing as in the question: `v1\nv2\nv3`. I couldn't add the line break.

Comment: didn't try it, but are you on windows? Maybe try "\r\n" as delimiter?

Comment: I'm on Windows and I did try with \r\n, with the same result.